# Removing certain columns

Tags: python, separation-of-concerns

So I have the below text file which goes on significantly. I wish to remove the 2nd and 3rd columns, and insert a "!" before the last column, in each row. I have been told I would probably need to write a Python code to do this, does anyone have a simpler solution. I have looked at previous posts but I could not see where text and numbers have been combined.

```
 AR
 E + AR > AR + E                 0.00    0     1  AR-ELASTIC
 E + AR > AR* + E               11.60    0     2  AR > AR*
 E + AR > AR*** + E             11.60    0  2382  AR > AR***
```

So my desired output would be in this case:

```
 AR
 E + AR > AR + E                    1  !AR-ELASTIC
 E + AR > AR* + E                   2  !AR > AR*
 E + AR > AR*** + E              2382  !AR > AR***
```

Comment: Insert it into Excel and handle it that way, if you don't want to write a script?

Comment: is that a singular task or do you need a recipe for programmatically handling the issue? in case the former applies, have a look at an editor with columns mode (ultraedit, iirc notepad++). otherwise, try [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) or write a short script (you aren't confined to python; perl or any other decent script language will do as well). as an aside, i take it from the tags that the file is the dump of a sql query result - can you modify that query (delete expr #2, 3 and prepend '!' to the last expression in the select clause).

Comment: Can you show what you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

Caveats:

- I presume you want your outlook to look like this:

  ```
  AR
  E + AR > AR + E                     1     !AR-ELASTIC
  E + AR > AR* + E                    2     !AR > AR*
  E + AR > AR*** + E                  2382  !AR > AR***
  ```
- I presume it is separated by tabs.

In python:

```
import csv

with open('yourfile', 'rb') as fin, open('youroutput', 'wb) as fout:
    tsvin = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    tsvout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')

    for row in tsvin:
        row_out = row[:1] + row[3:]
        row_out[-1] = '!{0}'.format(row_out[-1])
        tsvout.writerow(row_out)
```

You can read more about the [`csv` library here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Of course if any of my presumptions are wrong this may not fit your needs, please update your question with any information we are missing and I shall update/remove my answer as required.

Answer (score 0):

With same caveats as Ewan's, you can use awk, which very convenient to handle column in txt files :

```
$ cat toto
 AR
 E + AR > AR + E    0.00    0   1   AR-ELASTIC
 E + AR > AR* + E   11.60   0   2   AR > AR*
 E + AR > AR*** + E 11.60   0   2382    AR > AR***

awk -F"\t" '{if (NR==1) {printf $0} else {for (i=1;i<NF;i=i+1) {if(i!~2 && i!~3){printf $i"\t"} if (i==(NF-1)){printf "!"$NF }}}} {printf "\n"}' toto
```

where :

- NR is Number or record, and NR==1 i first line.
- F is field separator
- NF is Number of Field

Which gives :

```
 AR
 E + AR > AR + E    1   !AR-ELASTIC
 E + AR > AR* + E   2   !AR > AR*
 E + AR > AR*** + E 2382    !AR > AR***
```